# How to deal with metal dog in the beginning of Wolfenstein New Order?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

Don't understand this game.

Stuck in damaged airplane where metal dog (dino?) is penetrating inside and killing me. Game is loading very slow and the time of load is longer than my lifetime in this situation. So, the most time I am waiting for load. Then trying to do something for a few seconds before dog penetrates and die.

Nothing evident to do.

What to do here?

Answer (score 4):

Look to your right when facing the dog. There should be a crate blocking your exit. Smash the crate with your knife by clicking (or using the attack button if you're on console) and then escape.

Comment: I was asking about next step. I had stopped before sinking beneath the dog in the next room, was not knowing it is possible to crawl there.

Comment: @Dims The next step is to swim through water and reach the anti aircraft gun. Go to 12:08 in this video to see what to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oRenztJgzs

Answer (score -2):

sprint and slide underneath to get past it

Comment: Underneath what exactly? The dog?